# PostgresSQL: How to count up values in a row, then reset count when row value changes

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions

So I have the table below, I want to alter the table to display the second table, where I count up the number of IDs, then reset the count as I come to a different ID value.

Current Table

[image]

Desired Table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by case_number) cnt
from mytable t
```